# Step-by-step tutorial to install additional programmes to Ubuntu from USB ? eg. OPNsense

Tags: boot, software-installation, usb

I am new to Linux (but not to computer) and am trying to install a programme like OPNsense.

So far, I have managed the following type of installations :
1) install Ubuntu on a PC from USB (prepared on Windows with Rufus) and have a dual-mode laptop Ubuntu/Win10
2) install several applications via Ubuntu software (simple)
3) install a number of other software with a few instructions (CLI, need to be more familiar)

Here, to install a program like OPNsense, despite the install page (https://opnsense.org/users/get-started/), looks like I need to figure out quite a few steps to create a boot-able USB under Linux with the iso file of the software you want to install (eg. which file to download? how do you create a USB not to install Ubuntu but another programme - this time, with OPNsense, Rufus doesn't recognize the iso and don't know how to do it under Linux).

Could anyone suggest a step-by-step tutorial suitable for people new to Linux to create USB under Linux to install new programmes, using a bootable USB like for OPNsense ?

Many thanks,

Alex

Comment: Step-by-step instructions are at https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/install.html. Understanding the purpose and uses of OPNsense requires a minimum skill set, so more detailed instructions for unskilled users seems like wasted effort to me.

Comment: Thanks for the link but basically, it points to similar information as the one I mentioned "get-started". No worries with the purpose of OPNsense, I am ok with that, the issue is how to create a bootable USB with a image and install this on Linux. As mentioned OPNsense is just an example but this kind of information would be helpful with any Linux software requiring to be installed via USB as opposed to to Ubuntu Software or a few CLI. Any help on that kind of tutorial please ?

Comment: The "Startup Disk Creator" application is included with Ubuntu Desktop -- use Desktop Search to find it. That application does lead you through step-by-step to create a bootable USB from a downloaded image. Advanced users can use the `dd` command, just like the linked instructions show. Note that neither will work to make a Windows OS installer. Are you just asking for a primer on how to use Startup Disk Creator?